# Schengen Visa Cancelation

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, cancellations

I was wondering what sort of procedures a German consulate would have to follow/its obligation (or lack thereof) to communicate a visa cancelation to the traveler?

I have been issued a student visa for travel but I am paranoid that about them canceling it before my trip. It's a totally unfounded fear coming from my general anxiety disorder.....

Comment: A consulate won't arbitrarily cancel a visa. You'd have to do something that justifies that cancellation. Abuses of immigration law or felonies like murder might be reasons, but you would know that you committed those offences.

Comment: @ReddHerring unless they had the wrong person #thefugitive ! ;)

Comment: @ReddHerring Well let's hope that's not the situation OP is in. I too am curious though as to what the procedure is for informing the traveler if any.

Comment: Leaving aside felonies as a reason, a visa would only be annulled or revoked where it becomes evident that the conditions for issuing it were not met at the time when it was issued, in particular if there are serious grounds for believing that the visa was fraudulently obtained, or where the conditions for issuing it are no longer applicable (e.g. dropping out of your course).